# Correct use of footer tag in article

Tags: html, footer

I have an article (screenshot). It's obvious that header is the first image with heading under it. But how I need to use footer tag in this article? It's only "Share This Post" and "Related Posts" sections? Or only "Leave a comment" section? Or all starting from "Share this Post" till "Leave a comment" section?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From [W3C:](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-footer-element)

> A footer typically contains information about its section, such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like.
> A footer element can also contain entire sections representing appendices, indexes, long colophons, verbose license agreements, and other such content.

Judging from this i'd say "Related posts" could be a footer. Or maybe you shouldn't use footer at all.

Comment: It is OK if I use header in article, but don't have footer?

Comment: AFAIK neither header nor footer is mandatory for a html5 document. It's really a question of semantics.